# A last page with a word "secret" is printed

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, printing

Can anyone explain to me and tell me why there is a last page printed with a word "secret" after every image printed.

This does not happen to doc xls or even test page.

But when I print an image, immediately after the image page, a page with the word is printed with details of user, time date and etc.

OS: Kubuntu 15.10

The following is an example of the printed page:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the print dialog, check the *Job* tab for any *Before/After* cover page:

[image]

Comment: The Before and After is at default NONE for both.

Comment: Could you try to set it to something else (e.g. *Confidential*) and print with that, to see if the last printed page reflects the change?

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry that you're right.
I went down to desk to check on the system, there was a setting WITH BANNER ON but she claims not after few days ...
But weird, this only happens on IMAGE and does not happen on other docs llike ods pdf and etc BUT IMAGES

THANKS

Comment: Good, please accept the answer you believe was the most helpful in solving your issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a default banner (that can be used after the job as well) in cups (which I assume you use for printing.) Check in the print settings of your image program if it is set by any chance.

Comment: noted, will check.

update everyone

Comment: He said it does not happen with some file types, therefore it is probably not related to CUPS.

Comment: Well, that's why I wanted him to check in the image program settings and not in cups. :-)

Comment: Gosh, I actually missed that last part. My bad!

Comment: After checking the printer setting.

The banner front and end pages are set at default NONE. 

Nothing can be set at Image Viewer

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry that you're right.
I went down to desk to check on the system, there was a setting WITH BANNER ON but she claims not after few days ...
But weird, this only happens on IMAGE and does not happen on other docs llike ods pdf and etc BUT IMAGES